# HOWTO Fix Ugly Opera Font On Linux?

Tags: firefox, opera, rendering

I have two images to compare: [Opera version](http://yfrog.com/3tscreenshot2operap) and Firefox version
Look at how ugly the font rendered in opera. Did you guys have an idea how to fix it?

FYI:
1. I'm using Ubuntu Jaunty
2. With XFCE desktop (but, gnome and KDE4 is installed too)

Comment: for added information. The url is:
http://www.opera.com/company/jobs/list/

Comment: The url for firefox version is: http://yfrog.com/4oscreenshot1firefoxp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera has trouble using core X fonts, you can disable them though.

Under `~/.opera/opera#.ini` (where # represents version) add:

```
Enable Core X Fonts=0
```

in the `[User Prefs]` section of the file.

Comment: thanks, I did't use your solution though, because it fixed already when I use opera 10:D

Answer (score 4):

Some information available at an [Opera forums thread about the issue](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=251335).

Comment: sorry, I can't vote you UP, I don't have enough rep point